# Is there a way to get the Public DNS address of an instance?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2

I have a project wherein I need to update configuration files each time an EC2 instance is booted with the Public DNS  address of the current instance. I'll be using Perl or Sed for this, so that's not really the question, but the real question is: is there a way that I can determine the instance's public DNS address? Is there an EC2 api that I can access from the instance to determine it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is.  From inside the instance, you can run:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

To get the public DNS hostname, you can change that to:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

You can get the private IP for the instance, too:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

As a side note, you can double-check it against a non-AWS site on the internet, like http://ip4.me

```
#!/bin/bash

pubip=$( curl http://ip4.me 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's#<[^>]*>##g' | grep '^[0-9]' )

echo $pubip
```

That will work, generally, to check the "public IP" of any NATed system, or to find your public proxy IP, etc.

And here's a good link to read up on the types of information you can get from Amazon's API:
http://www.ducea.com/2009/06/01/howto-update-dns-hostnames-automatically-for-your-amazon-ec2-instances/

Comment: `PUBLIC_HOSTNAME="$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname 2>/dev/null)"` :) You, sir, are metal.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I define this function inside my .bashrc to retrieve the public ip and dns:

```
export PUBLIC_DNS=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname 2>/dev/null`
export PUBLIC_IP=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 2>/dev/null`

function get-pub() {
  if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Invalid number of arguments"
    return 1
  else
    case $1 in
      dns)
        echo $PUBLIC_DNS
        ;;
      ip)
        echo $PUBLIC_IP
        ;;
      *)
        echo $"Usage: get-pub {dns|ip}"
        return 2
    esac;
  fi
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install and configure [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (`aws configure`) and use the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-0xyz --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName' --output text
```

Comment: You can get your instance ID in serveral ways, using the ```ec2-metadata -i``` command or other means (i.e.: ```instanceId=$(cat /var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id)```.  Then you can pass that into #kenorb's example as a variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the dns name by tag.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-2 --max-items 1 --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=MyNameTag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName' --output text
```